# Can the convergence of odd-subseries and even-subseries implies the convergence of former series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am wondering that if this statement is true:

Let $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be a series of real numbers. Suppose there are  real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta,$ such that the odd-subseries and even subseries of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ satisfy
    \begin{gather*}
  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{2k-1}=\alpha,\qquad \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{2j}=\beta.\tag{$\star$}
 \end{gather*}
    Then  \begin{gather*}
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=\alpha+\beta.
 \end{gather*}

I think that probably it is true. And I have tried to prove it. Below is my proof. **Please check if it is valid.**

***Proof***
   $\quad $ By hypothesis of $(\star),$  we see that, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N_1, N_2\in\mathbb{N},$  for all $n\in\mathbb{N},$
    \begin{align*}
  &n>N_1\Rightarrow \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{2k-1}-\alpha\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2},\\
  &n>N_2\Rightarrow \left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{2j}-\beta\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.
 \end{align*}
    Put $N=2\max\{N_1, N_2\}+1.$ Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n>N.$   If $n$ is odd, then there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n=2m-1.$ And so $n=2m-1>2\max\{N_1, N_2\}+1\geq 2N_1+1>2N_1-1,$ which implies that $m>N_1.$  Furthermore, $$n-1=2m-2=2(m-1)>2\max\{N_1,N_2\}+1-1\geq 2N_2,$$  which leads to $m-1>N_2.$  Thus 
    \begin{align*}
  \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i-\alpha-\beta\right|&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{2m-1}a_i-\alpha-\beta\right|\\
  &\leq \left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{2k-1}-\alpha\right|+\left|\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}a_{2j}-\beta\right|<2\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.
 \end{align*}
    If $n$ is even, there $n=2l$ for some $l\in\mathbb{N}.$ Hence 
    $n=2l>2\max\{N_1,N_2\}+1,$ so $2l-1>2N_1>2N_1-1,$ which implies that $l>N_1.$ Since $n=2l>2\max\{N_1,N_2\}+1>2N_2,$ we see that $l>N_2.$  Thus we get 
    \begin{align*}
  \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i-\alpha-\beta\right|&=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{2l}a_k-\alpha-\beta\right|\\
  &\leq \left|\sum_{j=1}^{l}a_{2j}-\beta\right|+\left|\sum_{k=1}^{l}a_{2k-1}-\alpha\right|<2\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.
 \end{align*}
    In summary we have shown that $|\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i-\alpha-\beta|<\epsilon,$ provided $n>N.$  Therefore $\displaystyle
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n-1}=\alpha+\beta,
$  and so the proof is complete. $\qquad\qquad\Box$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s correct, but you’re working a bit harder than necessary. Just let $N=2\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ includes at least the first $N_1$ odd positive integers and at least the first $N_2$ even positive integers, so if $n>N$ is odd, then $n>2N_1-1$, and if $n>N$ is even, then $n>2N_2$. In particular, $n>N$ implies that

$$\large\left|\sum_{{1\le k\le n}\atop{k \text{ odd}}}a_k-\alpha\right|<\frac{\epsilon}2$$

and

$$\large\left|\sum_{{1\le k\le n}\atop{k\text{ even}}}a_k-\beta\right|<\frac{\epsilon}2\;.$$

Now you can finish it off in one go:

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^na_k-(\alpha+\beta)\right|\le\left|\sum_{{1\le k\le n}\atop{k \text{ odd}}}a_k-\alpha\right|+\left|\sum_{{1\le k\le n}\atop{k\text{ even}}}a_k-\beta\right|<2\cdot\frac{\epsilon}2=\epsilon\;.$$

Comment: Brilliant!  My choice of $N$ is not optimal! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @azc: You're very welcome.